# Why Graph.User[id].Authorization.PhoneMethods returns nothing although user has it set?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c

We have ADB2C where users have their 2FA set up with phonenumber and getting code through sms.

When I use `Graph.User[id].Authorization.PhoneMethods` for my user `Id` the method returns empty collection of `PhoneMethods`.

When I try `Graph.User[id].Authorization.Methods` the response indicates that user has only `passwordMethod`.

But, when I try to login with the user, it always asks me the verification code that is sent to my mobile phone number (and that works ok).

What might be wrong here?